Mother hijacks the hospital to save her child
It is a Hollywood film.
The story is:
The child (I can't remember if it was a boy or a girl) is admitted to hospital. The hospital does not treat her child because she can't pay the huge amount. The mother hijacked the hospital to save her child. 
Police arrived at the hospital and they send a female officer to talk to and catch the mother. After hearing the mother's story, the female officer joins with the mother, and forces the doctors to treat the child. 
The female officer has also other problems with her relationship. I think the officer's husband is a police officer.
At last the child is treated, and the mother surrenders. Can anyone identify the movie

This could be the TV movie FBI: Negotiator from 2005. From Lifetime's website:

Single mom and FBI agent Laura Martin is about to take her toughest case ever. She must negotiate with a desperate woman who has taken an entire hospital hostage in order to get her hands on an experimental drug for her daughter, who has cancer.



On Youtube, I only found this short clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Khtx-zjFkBY

Pretty much a ripoff of the Denzel Washington feature film "John Q".
